# Power circuitry not coming up

Tags: power-electronics, buck, converter

I've created a PCB that has two buck/boost converters, the second one being connected to the output of first one. The enable pin of the second buck converter is connected to the PG pin of the first buck converter, so whenever the first converter has a stable output, the second one will be turned on.

To convert 12-16 V down to 5 V, I'm using the TI TPS55165, in a design generated by WeBench.
To convert the 5 V to 3.3 V, I'm using the TPS63050, with the design generated by WeBench.

Now, whenever I try and power the PCB's, either the 5V circuitry comes on, the board draws quite some current (500 mA) and the 3V3 is around 5 V, or the 5 V power manager shuts down because of over current protection inside of the chip.

Today I've downloaded PSpice for TI to have a go at simulating the different designs and each design works individually, but when they are in series, the overall design stops working.

It does seem to replicate my real world scenario by some degrees, since the 3V3 output shoots up to around 6 V, before it stops working.

I just checked the simulation again and I'm not really expecting the 3V3 buck/boost controller to do anything really, since the 5V's PG is not yet active. (or, could it be that the EN pin has a different polarity than I thought)

This is the simulation schematic
[image: PSpice schematic]

This is the schematic as produced
[image: Schematic]

Debugging notes:

- Pulling down 5V PG, thus disabling the second state conversion, results in a clean 5V output, with regular current draw.
- One board sprung to life, with just a few mV's over on the 3V3 line (Around 3.5 V). It's strange because the example schematic (3V3 output) of this chip doesn't use a resistor divider on the feedback line, but WeBench suggested to use one. According to the simulation, the output voltage with the divider should be around 3.325 V
- Some of the boards draw a significant amount of current when supplying 5 V manually. The 3V3 circuitry tries to come alive, which is not working.
- On another board, when manually powering the 3V3 everything seems fine, but the 5 V circuitry does not work.

Here are some traces:
[image: Oscilloscope]

- Yellow: 3V3 line
- Pink: 5V PG
- Blue: 5V output

So what is this converter doing, it's not listening to it's enable input.
I've checked again in the datasheet and EN is tied to Vin in the example diagram, so EN polarity is active high with 5V input allowance.

Full vertical zoom, when taking these screenshots, the circuitry was loaded with 6 Ω.

5 V (0.83 A):
[image: 5V]

3V3 (0.55 A):
[image: 3V3]

The 3V3 circuitry seems to supply 3V3 only when loaded, when unloaded it supplies around 3.5-4 V.

Comment: Start with just one converter and a dummy load resistor. Hook up your oscilloscope and post oscillograms. How come there are no bootstrap capacitors?

Comment: Both of your converters are buck-boost converters, not buck converters.  Using actual buck converters would probably be cheaper and more efficient.  @winny has a good suggestion.  Also, try manually enabling the second converter well after the first converter comes up.  Does that work?  'Scope captures will be key in diagnosis.  (Input voltage, output voltage, switch nodes, PG signal, etc.)  And you do need bootstrap capacitors as winny pointed out.

Comment: @winny I'm using bootstrap capacitors on the first stage of the circuit. They are not moddeled in, so I left them out. I connected them on the board, per datasheet recommendation. As for the oscillograms, I'll update the question with them.

Comment: Please update your question with the exact schematic and values you are using. Post oscillograms.

Comment: @winny I've updated my question with more scope captures, are you still missing something?

Comment: _"The 3V3 circuitry seems to supply 3V3 only when loaded, when unloaded it supplies around 3.5-4 V."_ Is there a minimum load requirement?

Comment: By the control IC? I'm not aware of any minimum load requirement, although I think there is. When changing the static resistive load value to 136 Ohms (which is the maximum the WeBench can handle), we can see the output voltage hover at around 3.5V. I think this will conclude that I've to redo my power circuitry